# Is there a way to use the DBContext class to access a entity whose table was created in OnModelCreating() the way a DBSet<T> is used?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two classes: Article and Category.  The Article owns the Category.  In the DBContext(via EntityConfig file) I have the following being configured:

```
    jsConfiguration.OwnsMany(article => article.Categories, s =>
    {
        s.WithOwner();
        s.Property<DateTime>("CreatedDate");
        s.Property<DateTime>("UpdatedDate");
        s.ToTable("ArticleBaseCategories");
    });
```

Please accept that I have to configure it this way and not able to use DBSet.

I want to be able to use syntax similar to if I had a DBSet Categories property defined in my DBSeedClass.  For example:

```
_context.Categories.Where(category => category.Name == "example")
```

Is there a way to do this without actually creating a DBSet<> property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Many different entities in your model can have the same owned entity type mapped to different tables, so EF wouldn't know where to fetch them.  You can use Dapper and a raw SQL query to fetch them.  Or fetch some Article entities, and then run `.SelectMany(a => a.Categories)` on the client.